# Using "to which"

Tags: sentence-construction

> I have a question in my mind ***to which*** I can't get a clear
>   answer.

Is this usage of "to which" correct?

or Can I just use "that" here:

> I have a question in my mind ***that*** I can't get a clear answer.

Comment: You could say "I have a question in mind that I can't answer clearly" or "I have a question for which I can't get a clear answer"

Comment: Thanks. Using "to which" is wrong then?